# Drupal 7 Feeds Module XML importing

Tags: xml, drupal

Create a content type "test system" with 2 fields
Content type: test system
    field: 
    id, integer
    name, text

Create a XML file, and upload it to the server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<result>
<id>298</id>
<name>This is ID 298 description</name>
</result>
<result>
<id>452</id>
<name>This is ID 452 description</name>
</result>
</response>
```

Create an Feed Importer to use this uploaded file to create/update "test system" content.

But it is not importing content feeds.
It doesnot display any error, but displays only a message i.e "There are no new nodes". 
There are no new nodes.
STATUS: No imported items.

The modules are:

Feeds 7.x-2.0-alpha8+68-dev Aggregates RSS/Atom/RDF feeds, imports CSV files and more.

Feeds Admin UI 7.x-2.0-alpha8+68-dev Administrative UI for Feeds module.

Feeds Tamper 7.x-1.0-beta3+52-dev Modify feeds data before it gets saved.

Feeds Tamper Admin UI 7.x-1.0-beta3+52-dev Administrative UI for Feeds Tamper module.

Feeds XPath Parser 7.x-1.0 Parse an XML or HTML document using XPath.

Comment: I assume that you have mapped your fields already in the importer? You it might help to take a look at http://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-what-i-learnt-from-hours-of-troubleshooting-feeds/#xml-import for an idea of setting up the mapper. I believe in this case your "Context" would be //response

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem when importing feeds. The problem was incorrect mapping for Node processor so the XML was "processed" but it could not load data into Drupal.

Take a good look at the XML file and indentation.

These are the pages where your have to set the correct values: /admin/structure/feeds/indeed_feed/mapping and /admin/structure/feeds/indeed_feed/settings/FeedsXPathParserXML

The context in your case has to be "//result" so you can access the fields. The to forward slashes mean two indentations in the XML file.

Can you post an screenshot of this exact page in your Drupal installation?